# How to stop rails appending www.html.com to beginning of URLS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have implemented some coffeescript that allows my table rows to be links.

The issue I am having however is that my app seems to be adding `http.com//` into the beginning of my Job URLs so instead of getting `www.google.com` I would get `www.http.com//www.google.com`

I have the current setup:

```
#Coffeescript

$ ->
  $('tr[href]').click -> window.open 'http://' + $(this).attr('href');


#View
    <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
        <tr href='<%= job.job_url %>'>
            <td><strong><%= job.title %></strong></td>
            <td><%= job.company %></td> 
            <td><%= job.city %>, <%= job.country %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

The URLs stored in my database all have `www.` as part of the URL but not `http://`.

Any advice on what might be going on here would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`job_url` returns a complete url, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/jobs/1234
```

whereas `job_path` returns a relative path, e.g.

```
'/jobs/1234'
```

If you are going to use `job_url`, you should NOT append the protocol in your coffeescript, as your URLs will be horked because they will be appending the protocol twice.

You might also consider, as a best practice, to use `data-href` as the attribute on your `<tr>`.  I try to do this, it makes the link between the HTML and the Javascript more explicit.  I have spent many an hour tracking down bugs where the designer removed or renamed a class or attribute element that my Javascript was relying upon!

So, in your ERB:

```
<tr data-href='<%= job.job_url %>'>
```

In the Coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('tr[data-href]').click -> window.open 'http://' + $(this).attr('data-href');
```

Comment: Hi ipd, thanks for your answer. Would you recommend coffeescript like this `$('tr[href]').click -> window.open $(this).attr('href');`? If this looks wrong could you possibly update your answer with a quick example just so I fully understand the elements I should be changing. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: I'd give you an extra upvote for the "don't put an `href` on a `<tr>`" advice but, alas, I'm only allowed one. An `href` on a [`<tr>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/tr.html) is invalid HTML and invalid HTML can cause interesting bugs.

Comment: Hey IPD, Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working, now when I click on the table row nothing happens. Do you have any idea why? Thanks!